# Get First date and Last date of week after given a date in dd-mmm-yyyy format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am giving Date in dd-MMM-yyyy format like 01-dec-2013 and i want start date and end date of the week.

After i change the given date by on button click like left and right arrow i want right start and end date of the week,

So please help me for this, using Jquery

Comment: do you have jQuery UI or any other date parser

Comment: Last day of the week in which country? Or localized to the browser locale?

Comment: The spec is your friend: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var date = new Date('03-dec-2013');
var day =date.getDay();

var start = new Date(date)
start.setDate(start.getDate() - day)
console.log(start)

var end = new Date(date)
end.setDate(end.getDate() - day + 6)
console.log(end)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vLYDT/)

*Note: The parsing of the date string may not be supported in all environments, need to confirm that. For a safer parsing use a date library like momentjs*

Comment: Hey Dear, Thanks for your replay but this solution is not helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/56cHF/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $('#date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));

        }
    });
});
```

---

[onSelect:](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#anydate').datepicker({
        showWeek:true,
        firstDay:0,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        onSelect: function() {
            var d = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var tstamp = $.datepicker.formatDate('@',d);
            var wd = d.getDay();
            var wkstart = new Date();
            wkstart.setDate(d.getDate() - wd);
            var wkend = new Date();
            wkend.setDate(d.getDate() + (7 - wd));
            $('#weekstart').val(wkstart.toDateString());
            $('#weekend').val(wkend.toDateString());
    }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="anydate" id="anydate" />
<input type="text" id="weekstart" />
<input type="text" id="weekend" />
```

[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/aA9M3/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/). It saves all such work by allowing to write code like:

```
moment(input).day(0); // Sunday of this week
moment(input).day(6); // Saturday of this week
moment(input).day(-7); // last Sunday (0 - 7)
moment(input).day(7); // next Sunday (0 + 7)
moment(input).day(10); // next Wednesday (3 + 7)
moment(input).day(24); // 3 Wednesdays from now (3 + 7 + 7 + 7)
```

And it can parse various formats of date strings.